# Проблема с парсингом сайта

Tags: php, curl

Есть сайт, на нем есть input в котором в поле value генерится код с каждым обновлением страницы. 
Мне нужно получить этот код через парсер.
Проблема в том, что код я получил и у меня он не меняется, обновляю страницу и вижу тот же код. Думаю проблема может быть связана с кэшем.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://belkraj.by/user?destination=user');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // следовать за редиректами
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);// просто отключаем проверку сертификата
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'); // сохранять куки в файл
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,  dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$html = new Simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('https://belkraj.by/user?destination=user');
foreach ($html->find('input[name="form_build_id"]') as $element) {
    echo $element->value . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'); // сохранять куки в файл
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,  dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
Удаляйте эти строки  =)

Comment: А вы уверены, что код генерируется каждый раз при обновлении страницы?